# Custom cliparts in Android Studio 0.4+?

Tags: android, android-studio, assets

How to add custom cliparts to "New Image asset" dialog in Android Studio 0.4+ ?

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio040released

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files under the **Clipart** radio button are hardcoded into Android Studio and aren't intended to be customized. If you have your own artwork, that's what the **Image** radio button is for.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/idea133/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/wizard/AssetSetStep.java starting at line 297.